The orthogonal complement of tensor product in Hilbert spaces
In this post it has been asked a question that interests me. However, I have not been able to find any reference for this equation or any similar one.
My assumptions are: let $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ be real Hilbert spaces and $U\subseteq \mathcal{K}$ a closed subspace. Is it true that
$$(U\otimes\mathcal{H})^\perp=U^\perp\otimes\mathcal{H}?$$
If it is true, which book or paper this equality appears in?

Hint. The functor $- \otimes \mathcal{H}$ preserves orthogonal direct sums.

I hope I got it right. Since $\mathcal{K}=U\oplus U^\perp$, then $\mathcal{K}\otimes\mathcal{H}=(U\oplus U^\perp)\otimes\mathcal{H}$. Now, the functor $-\otimes\mathcal{H}$ preserves orthogonal direct sums, so $(U\oplus U^\perp)\otimes\mathcal{H}=(U\otimes\mathcal{H})\oplus (U^\perp\otimes\mathcal{H})$ and hence, $U^\perp\otimes\mathcal{H}=(U\otimes\mathcal{H})^\perp$. Is that correct?

Yes but you need to work out the details. This is the outline.

Justifying the last step better, I would say. Thank you very much for your quick response.Also, I have found a useful identity in Werner's Greub's Multilinear Algebra, 2nd Edition, Problem 2 (b) of page 35. Let $E$ and $F$ be inner product spaces, $E^$ and $F^$ their duals and $U\subseteq E$ and $W\subseteq F$. Then $(U\otimes W)^\perp = U^\perp\otimes F^* + E^*\otimes W$. This is a generalization of my question: taking $F=\mathcal{H}$ and noticing that $\mathcal{H}$ is self-dual, one has the desired result.
